How does the manifest gets parsed and processed by the Android OS?
In the Android manifest file, we use the uses-feature tag so that the app can use a specific hardware or a software feature. How does the Android OS handle this tag internally and gives the access to specific hardware or software feature at the OS level? Whats the entry-point for the parsing of Android app manifest and how is it processed at the OS level internally
At installation time <uses-feature>  with required=true are checked if the device has the required hardware/software, otherwise app installation will fail.

Short Answer

Declares a single hardware or software feature that is used by the application.

As mentioned here
The <uses-feature> tag inside the AndroidManifest.xml is used to show the needed hardware and software facilities for the proper functioning of your app.
Syntax :
<uses-feature
  android:name="string"
  android:required=["true" | "false"]
  android:glEsVersion="integer" />


TL;DR
How this is processed by android system:
Parsing <uses-feature> Tag:
At the parsing stage, which occurs, for example, at the time of installation, the PackageParser class included in the PackageManager component, encounters the tags <uses-feature>.
Each <uses-feature> tag has parameters that point to the feature required by the application.
These attributes can include:

android:name: This describes the particular name of the feature, (android:name=“camera”).
android:needed: A boolean value that determines whether the feature is necessary or not, (by default set to True).
Other version-specific attributes depending on the feature (e.g.,android:add the attribute requiredIfEmpty="true" for Bluetooth LE).

Processing Feature Requirements:
Once the parser identifies the features declared within the <uses-feature> tags, the system takes several actions:

Feature Availability Check:
It guarantees that actually the particular device that the app is being installed on possesses the required capabilities. This involves using the identification process in order to determine, some of the harder ware and software features of the device.

Filtering and Installation:


Based on the feature availability check:

All Features Available: If all of such mandatory functions (android:required=”true”) are present in the device, then the download of an application is normal.


Missing Features:


If a required feature is missing (android:required="true" the installation process could be stopped or a message could appear to the user that system is not suitable for some features.




For features with `android:required=”false” system might proceed with the installation but the app might not be as effective if it lacks the particular feature.




Runtime Behavior:
Tag of <uses-feature> could also be effectively used at the run time to determine whether the said feature is available when the application is running.
They use it less often because some of them are not integrated into every device due to its tremendous number of functions, the presence of which is physically impossible (such as the NFC chip).

Important Considerations:

This <uses-feature> tag should be used properly, the application intends to use the features declared in it. Stating undeclared features can cause the app to not run well or at all on devices that do not have particular features.


<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar"
android:required="true" />



Take example, of  android.hardware.camera.ar which I have used in my project signifies app requires ARCore, a feature for augmented reality. If a user's device lacks ARCore (checked by the  tag), Google Play hides your app from their search results to avoid compatibility issues. This ensures users only see apps their devices can actually run.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#market-feature-filtering
Reference links :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element


This example code is ADT tools, but the same happens on-device with AndroidManifestParser.java, which parses it to ManifestData.java.
XML node uses-feature is being represented as ManifestData.UsesFeature.
When required features are missing, this means "incompatible" with the device.
Setting property "required" to true only makes sense for core functionality.
